# Graphing current_user data with Chartkick Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I've been having trouble with capturing the data related to the current_user, and then graphing it. I will post the code that I've written and error that I've been experiencing below.

I'm receiving the error below, even though the view itself loads

```
Error Loading Chart: Internal Server Error
```

Index.html.erb

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= line_chart analytic_posts_created_path(current_user) %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Analytics_Controller.rb

```
class AnalyticsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    posts_created
  end

  def posts_created
    render json: current_user.posts.group_by_month(:created_at).count
  end

  private
  def set_user
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :analytics, only: [:index] do
    get '/posts_created' => 'analytics#posts_created'
  end
```

Application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://www.google.com/jsapi', 'chartkick' %>
```

Server Log

```
Started GET "/analytics.john190" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-29 17:46:50 -0400
Processing by AnalyticsController#index as 
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT count(*) as count, strftime( "%Y-%m-01 00:00:00 UTC", created_at ) as date_slice FROM "Posts" WHERE "Posts"."user_id" = ? AND ("Posts"."created_at" IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY date_slice  ORDER BY "Posts"."created_at" DESC, date_slice  [["user_id", 5]]
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Are you trying to render json? If yes then you should use `json` and not `jsons`.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a typo. Thank you for noticing. My problem now is the number 1 (for number of items created_by_month) being shown in the view, instead of the line graph itself.

Comment: where is your code to print line graph?

Comment: Everything that I wrote so far is inside of the question block.

Comment: In the analytics index view. It's only showing the number, btw. The navigation bar is not being rendered at all.

Answer (score 0):

I took the traditional approach of using instance variables instead of JSON. The JSON approach overrides the html views.

analytics_controller.rb

```
def index
    @user_monthly_articles = current_user
    @user_monthly_articles.articles.group_by_year(:created_at).count
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= line_chart @user_monthly_articles %>
    </div>
  </div>
```